# Set a http socket timeout correctly in camel 3

Tags: spring-boot, http, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

Having this Spring-XML config

```
<to uri="http://localhost:8088/?httpMethod=GET&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;socketTimeout=10000&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
```

I've got a `socketTimeout is a custom option that is not part of the Camel component` warning in IntelliJ IDEA.
Indeed, in [camel-docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html) I see socketTimeout in Component Options and other options from the snippet above are in Query Parameters, so the question is if socketTimeout should be specified differently? What is the correct way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is defined as component option so it can't be used from the endpoint uri. If you are using spring, you can do something like https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/configuring-camel.html#ConfiguringCamel-WorkingwithSpringXML to configure the timeout on the component.